# self hosted video player/soution with fallback

Tags: 6, files

I use drupal 6 and I am looking for a way to play my own videos (only one per product page). 
I use views to display content.
Player should have ability to fallback to browser player for users with javascript disabled. 
Similar solution is implemented on zappos page for example here http://www.zappos.com/reef-fanning-brown-lux?zfcTest=fcl%3A0

If I click on video with javacsript disabled, I get a new window with video playing.

Can anybody recommend a solution? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use:

https://drupal.org/project/jwplayermodule

> - Full support for JW Player for Flash and HTML5.
> - Manage multiple custom players.
> - Full skin and plugin support with easy to use plugin customization interface.
> - A powerful shortcode system for customizations at embed time.
> - CCK Field support.
> - Integration with the popular FileField module.
> - Integration with the Embedded Media Field module.